# DateTime from SQL database with value null

Tags: c#, sql, mvvm

I want to get datetime from SQL database and store it in a DateTime property.
At the moment it has value null.
I keep getting conversion error.
Programming in C# with MVVM.

```
private void LoadFunctie()
    {
        _myModel = new ObservableCollection<myModel>();
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        DT = 
        clsDAC.ExecuteDataTable(Properties.Resources.S_myStoredProcedure);
        foreach (DataRow DR in DT.Rows)
        {
            var x = new clsOrderOverzichtM()
            {
                SomeID = (int)DR[0],//works
                SomeString = DR[1].ToString(),//works
                SomeDate = (DateTime)DR[2]//ERROR

            };
            _myModel.Add(x);
        }
    }
```

My Property

```
    private DateTime? _SomeDate;
    public DateTime? SomeDate
    {
        get { return _SomeDate; }
        set
        {
            _SomeDate = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

What could be my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the column allows `null` values then you have to check for [DBNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull(v=vs.110).aspx) when you read from it. The easiest way to do this on a [DataRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow(v=vs.110).aspx) is with [IsNull](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chk182xa(v=vs.110).aspx). The line of code would then be:

```
SomeDate = DR.IsNull(2) ? null : (DateTime?)DR[2]
```

The assignment type you are using should then also be nullable or have an acceptable default value.